# How to subtract backwards in a list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to subtract a list backwards in Python. This is the code:

```
list_1 = [1,2,5,7,9,85]
```

The subtraction should go like this: index 1 - index 0, index 2 - index 1, and so on and so forth. This is the output:

```
1
3
2
2
76
```

How can i do something like this using Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `map` and `operator` and `itertools.islice`, this way you are avoiding intermediate lists creation or memory overhead and also avoids using python native `for` loop:

```
import operator
from itertools import islice
list_1 = [1,2,5,7,9,85]

result = list(map(operator.sub, islice(list_1, 1, None),list_1))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/AnguishedQuickwittedPattern)

Comment: This one's much better, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
[i - j for i, j in zip(list_1[1:], list_1)]
```

Comment: One liner! nice one!

Comment: @TaohidulIslam, an ideomatic solution, not the best  one any way, he is actually creating 2 intermediate lists out of nowhere

Comment: yes. And `zip(list_1[1:], list_1)` at least saves 1 creation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a good old-fashioned for loop:

```
for i in range(1, len(list_1)):
    print list_1[i]-list_1[i-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_1 = [1,2,5,7,9,85]
for i in range(len(list_1)-1,1,-1):
    list_1[i] = list_1[i]-list_1[i-1]
print(list_1)
```

Note: iterate backwards to get expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using list comprehension.

Iterate from zero to the penultimate index and do the subtraction.

```
[ (list_1[i+1] - list_1[i]) for i in range(len(list_1)-1)]
```

Comment: Add some description to your answer so that any user can understand

Answer (score 0):

```
    print [a[i+1]- a[i] for i in range(len(a)-1)]
```

This one-liner returns a list whose elements are the difference of consecutive numbers in list_1.